# Create a Trigger in SQL for which you need the primary key

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, mariadb

I tried to create a trigger in PLSQL for which you need the primary key. The pk is used to join tables together in order to get another identifier. The only problem is that I only get 'HQ' (the default value of v_erg) when I insert values into the table. My guess at least is that the value of :new.par_nr (the pk) is not defined in the before trigger, because when i change the :new.par_nr to a number like 1 it works fine. Can someone help me out?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_pk_parts
BEFORE INSERT ON Parts
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_erg VARCHAR(100) := 'HQ';
v_decpow VARCHAR(100);
v_unit VARCHAR(100);
v_value INTEGER;
v_temp VARCHAR(100);
Cursor c_addprop IS
SELECT pap_value, uni_short, dep_short from Parts p 
inner join Parts_AdditionalProperties pap on p.par_nr = pap.pap_par_nr 
INNER join AdditionalProperties ap on pap.pap_adp_nr =ap.adp_nr
INNER JOIN Units u on ap.adp_uni_nr =u.uni_nr
Inner join DecimalPowers dp on ap.adp_dep_nr =dp.dep_nr
WHERE par_nr =:new.par_nr; 
Begin
SELECT pas_description into v_temp from PartStyles ps
inner join Parts p on p.par_pas_nr =ps.pas_nr 
WHERE p.par_nr = :new.par_nr; 
v_erg := v_erg||v_temp;
SELECT pva_description into v_temp from PartValues pv
inner join Parts p on p.par_pva_nr = pv.pva_nr 
WHERE p.par_nr =:new.par_nr; 
v_erg := v_erg||v_temp;
OPEN c_addprop;
LOOP
FETCH c_addprop INTO v_value,v_unit,v_decpow;
EXIT WHEN c_addprop%NOTFOUND;
v_erg := v_erg||v_value||v_decpow||v_unit;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_addprop;
:new.par_nr_hq := v_erg;
END;
```

Comment: pls tag the appropriate database: mysql and oracle are 2 different databases, you can't have both at the same time. How is the primary key on the PARTS table generated ? Is this an identity column or a sequence ?

Comment: I used AUTO_INCREMENT to automatically generate a new pk when i insert a new dataset

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with mariadb - you had tagged this as oracle which is why I replied

Comment: Code you posted looks like Oracle. PL/SQL tag you used *means* Oracle. Are you sure you use MariaDB?

Comment: Yeah i am using mariadb with SQL_MODE=ORACLE. With that i can use PL/SQL code with mariadb